# Embedding a browser into Java Application for getting video stream

Tags: java, swing

Is there some sort of library that I can use to embed a browser into a JPanel so that I can watch a stream from twitch.tv or ustream.tv??

I've looked around and found http://www.developer.com/java/ent/article.php/3644196/Eclipse-Tip-Create-Rich-User-Interfaces-with-the-HTML-Browser-Widget.htm

but it looks like it's only HTML compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you want to see and how it is streamed:

**You wants to see the web page twitch.tv:**

You can use the SWT Browser widget, a 3rd party Swing HTMLPanel or going with JavaFX2.

**You wants to see only the stream:**

If the stream is Flash I think there is nothing to do. If it is HTML5 you can go with JavaFX2.